# bcrypt.compareSync is always returning false

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I verified that in my db I am saving the username and hash of the password.  I am able to retrieve the name from the db, however when I check the password it always returns false.  Not sure what is wrong.

Here is my HTML

```
<div ng-controller="userController"> 
    <div class=user>
        <form name="login_form">
            <h2 class>Login</h2>
            <h3 class = "login_page">UserName</h3>
            <input ng-model="user" type="text" ng-minlength="1" required>
            <h3 class = "login_page">Password</h3>
            <input ng-model="password" type="password" name="password" ng-minlength="4" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" ng-click="login()" >
            <div ng-if ="login_form.$submitted" ng-messages="login_form.password.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
                <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
            </div>
            <p ng-if="error">Username or login is incorrect</p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class=user>
        <form name = "register_form">
            <h2 class>Register</h2>
            <h3 class = "login_page">UserName</h3>
            <input ng-model="reg.name" type="text" required>
            <h3 class = "login_page">Password</h3>
            <input ng-model="reg.password" type="password">
            <input type="submit" value="Register" ng-click="register()" required >
            <div ng-if ="login_form.$submitted" ng-messages="login_form.password.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
                <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
            </div>
            <p ng-if="duplicate">That user name is taken, please choose another</p>
            <p ng-if="correct">Registration Succesfull</p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller on the server side

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Todo = mongoose.model('Todo');
Login = mongoose.model('Login');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var name = ""

module.exports = (function(){
  return {
    save_name:function(req, res){
        req.session.user = req.body.user
      Login.findOne({name: req.body.user},
      function(err, user) {
        if(user){
          console.log(user.password);
            console.log( bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password));
           res.json({'error': false}); 
          }else {
            res.json({'error': true});
          }
      })
    }, //end of save name method
    register:function(req, res){
      bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8));
      login = new Login({
        name:req.body.user,
        password: bcrypt.genSaltSync(8)
      })
      login.save(function(err){
        if(err){
          res.json({'error': true});
        } else {
          res.json({'sucess': true})
        }
      })
    } // end of register user function
  } 
})();
```

Comment: I had the same problem and my mistake was to store the hash password as a `char(64)` and not as a `varchar(64)` so that extra blank characters were each time taken into account in the `bcrypt.compareSync()` function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're saving a generated salt as the password instead of the actual hash itself. Also, explicitly calling `genSalt*()` is unnecessary. Lastly, you really should use the async functions instead, to avoid unnecessarily blocking the event loop. So with all of this in mind, you may end up with something like:

```
module.exports = {
  save_name: function(req, res) {
    req.session.user = req.body.user;
    Login.findOne({ name: req.body.user },
                  function(err, user) {
      if (err)
        return res.json({ error: true });
      bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,
                     user.password,
                     function(err, valid) {
        res.json({ error: !!(err || !valid) }); 
      });
    });
  }, // end of save name method
  register: function(req, res) {
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 8, function(err, hash) {
      if (err)
        return res.json({ error: true });
      login = new Login({
        name: req.body.user,
        password: hash
      })
      login.save(function(err) {
        res.json({ error: !!err });
      })
    });
  } // end of register user function
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Despite other answers, if it is still not resolving your issue. Try by applying the **toString()** when passing the password upon login like this.

**req.body.password.toString();**

Comment: Strangely enough, this suggestion fixed the problem in my case, though I don't really see how applying `toString()` to something that already is a string would make any difference. @AhmerSaeed can you explain how you came up with this solution and why it works?

Comment: I guess there was a bug in the bcrypt package at that time. Because, when i am trying this now without using .toString() it is working fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate cause of your bug is in `register` you should be using `bcrypt.hashSync(myPlaintextPassword, saltRounds)` instead of `genSaltSync`. Fixing that should make things "work".

However, you need to recode all this to use the async bcrypt APIs or your application will respond very poorly under load (like crippled and unusable, not just "slow"). General rule: no sync calls in a node.js server.

Comment: What do you mean by async bcrypt apis @Peter Lynos

Answer (score 0):

This snippet works for me.

```
userSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
  const password = this.password;
  const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
  this.password = hashedPassword;
  this.confirmPassword = undefined;
  next();
});

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (password, hash) {
  let isPasswordValid;
  isPasswordValid = bcrypt.compare(password, hash);
  return isPasswordValid;
};
```